# Recursive function to flatten any list in Python (2.7) is not working

Tags: python, function, debugging, recursion

I want to be able to flatten any nested one-dimensional list.  I want the results printed.
I have three sample lists to get started with.  I am getting an error when I try to run my file.

Here is the code:

```
import collections, itertools

listoflists = [[3, 12], [223, [[44], 1]], 6]
listoflists2 = [[9, 38], [7, [[36], 5]], 4]
listoflists3 = [[1, 72], [3, [[4], 35]], 6, [7]]

print 'Option 1 is:'
print listoflists
print 'Option 2 is:'
print listoflists2
print 'Option 3 is:'
print listoflists3

userInput = raw_input("Which Option do you want?")
userInput = int(userInput)

listsvent = []

if(userInput == 1): userOption = listoflists
elif(userInput == 2): userOption = listoflists2
elif(userInput == 3): userOption = listoflists3; print "We're using Option 3";

class powerQ1:
        def flatten(self, uo):
            for bb in uo:
                if isinstance(bb, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(bb, basestring):
                        for sub in flatten(bb):
                                print sub
                else:
                        print bb

s = powerQ1()
s.flatten(userOption)
```

Here is the error:

```
 python p1cp.py
Option 1 is:
[[3, 12], [223, [[44], 1]], 6]
Option 2 is:
[[9, 38], [7, [[36], 5]], 4]
Option 3 is:
[[1, 72], [3, [[4], 35]], 6, [7]]
Which Option do you want?1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p1cp.py", line 34, in <module>
    s.flatten(userOption)
  File "p1cp.py", line 28, in flatten
    for sub in flatten(bb):
NameError: global name 'flatten' is not defined
```

What is wrong?  Recursion is difficult.

Comment: That name **isn't** defined globally, did you mean `self.flatten`? And why is it in a class?

Comment: Well that error is due to the fact that you must call member functions via `self`. In the loop it would be `self.flatten(bb)` not just `flatten(bb)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for sub in flatten(bb):
```

You call global function `flatten` here which is not defined (it is said by Exception message!). Call `flatten` method:

```
for sub in self.flatten(bb):
```

Comment: I made one modification.  I used the "self." before the flatten call on line 28.  But now I get this error:

`code`  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q1new.py", line 34, in <module>
    s.flatten(userOption)
  File "q1new.py", line 28, in flatten
    for sub in self.flatten(bb):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable `code`

I don't understand because I have log with an if pre-condition to test Iterability.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: Why do you use `for sub in self.flatten(bb)` in a first place? It doesn't have `return` statement and not a generator, so it just returns `None` that triggers an exception. Probably simple call of `self.flatten(bb)`should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You're using flatten recursively in the definition of flatten, but in the context of the method you use it as though it were a function, and not a method, when in fact it is a method on the powerQ1 type object.

In other words, look at the recursive call. That should be something like self.flatten([other stuff here]) instead of just a bare call to flatten(), since the global function flatten doesn't exist. Remember, explicit is better than implicit. As such, in Python, you have to specify the object calling when you use a method, even in class scope. This is different than Java where you don't have to specify the calling object when it is implicit in the non-static class context.

TL;DR: flatten is a bound method, not a function. You have to factor that in to your recursive calls. Remember, explicit is always better than implicit.